# Windows 10 pro cannot see itself on Network

Tags: windows, networking

I am having an issue with Windows Networking. I have two laptops, and one desktop computer. The desktop is plugged in via ethernet to the router, while the two laptops are wireless. The two laptops can communicate with one another flawlessly. My desktop can communicate with the laptops just fine as well. Read write files, etc. All three computers can ping one another in command prompt, no issues.

My desktop computer is not visible in the network tab of file explorer at all. It cannot even see itself. I can navigate to the desktop using the run window on one of the laptops, but not the other. I can access the external hard drive that has been shared, but not the internal drives of the desktop. This is really annoying because last night I had all of this working just fine.

The desktop is running Windows 10 Pro, while the two laptops are running Windows 10 Home.

The weirdest thing to me is that the desktop cannot even see itself in the network tab of file explorer. I have gone into the network and sharing center and made all of the changes that the standard google search recommends. Does anyone have any ideas?

***Edit***

I did a reset of the network settings on my desktop, then reenabled the network discovery and file sharing. My desktop can now see itself on the network, and I can access the other computers on the network as well. Everything seems to be working now. Will do a restart on everything, and get back to you all.

***Edit***

After the restart, the desktop is no longer visible on the network on the desktop itself, or on one of the laptops. The other laptop can see it just fine. Laptop 1 can see the desktop, and can access it, but only via file explorer. Navigating directly through the run menu does not work. Laptop 2 cannot see the desktop, but can navigate to it via the run menu. Desktop can see both laptops, and access them just fine, but cannot navigate to itself via the run menu. All machines can see the desktop as a media server and stream music.

Comment: On the problem computer, look in Network and Sharing center, advanced sharing settings.  Make sure Network Discovery is ON. If you have a printer, make sure File and Print Sharing is ON. Make sure Password Protected sharing is ON.  See if you are sharing Public Folders and if that needs to be enabled.

Comment: I did have one folder that was causing an issue due to improper permissions. I did a reset of the network settings on the problem computer, which seems to have fixed it. I am going to do a restart on all three, and hope it still works at that point.

Comment: It sounds like you are relying on the SMB protocol which can be problematic.  Check to see in 'Turn Windows features on or off' if you SMB Direct enabled and whether SMB 1.0 support is enabled.  It might be on some, but not others.

It also could be a corrupt netbios shares - this guy wrote a beautiful tool to recorrect these problems https://github.com/filippobottega/ShareFix